# How to break a string in lines

Tags: .net, regex, string, lines

I'm confused with what is the correct way to break lines.

I read somewhere that windows use \r\n to break lines, but this two codes produce the same

```
regex.split(sometext, "\r\n");
regex.split(sometext, "\n");
```

What it is the correct way?, these expressions always produce the same?

Comment: First - this isn't C#. .Net has `Regex.Split`. Next, you could provide more details - do you need to preserve empty lines? Where does the data come from?

Comment: @Kobi He could have just written this from memory, which could explain the incorrect casing.

Comment: @NKCSS - That's a very poor practice when asking a question `:)`

Comment: Just FYI: They probably don't produce the same. The second statement should still contain the "\r" character (carriage return) but you may not see it.

Comment: @Kobi sorry about the case, i'm accustomed to write without worry about the case and use ctrl-space to fixit ;), and also because i was playing with that expression in Powershell that has a case insensitive language, so i'm very habituated. You could see it as simply .net and not c#, i make the mistake in tagging as c#. The data as i say is a string, so it is in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to support new-line characters for every platform (e.g. you need to parse input files, created under Linux/Windows/Mac in your ASP.NET web-site) and you do not carry about empty strings, I suggest to use this method instead:

```
myString.Split(new char[] { '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

This will return

```
["one","two","three"]
```

for input string

```
"one\r\ntwo\n\n\nthree"
```

**Update:**
If you need to carry about empty lines, you can use

```
myString.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Split("\n")
```

This should work for both "\r\n" and "\n" EOL charracter files.

Comment: great idea i'm going to use it. And if i the string has an heterogenous ending i could add one replace more to delete (very improbably to happen) invisibles CR.... myString.Replace("\r\n","\n").replace("\r","").split("\n")

Answer (score 12):

Use

```
var myArray = sometext.Split(Environment.NewLine);
```

`Environment.NewLine` will pick the correct one for your operating system. This will fail if the data was created on a different system. Something that might work on all systems, but have some unintended consequences is

```
var myArray = sometext.Split(new[] {'\r', '\n'}, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Some possible worrisome things is that it will remove all empty lines and split on carriage returns.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) to make sure you get the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

\r is a [carriage return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return)
\n is a [newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_feed).

Windows uses \r\n by default <strike>(Environment.NewLine)</strike>.

[Rewritten to clarify the Environment.NewLine part]

To get the correct characters to split your text on, you can use [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx), which will report the correct characters based on your platform.

Comment: @NKCSS: You basically repeated the information given in the original question and ignored the question itself. Please consider improving your answer.

Comment: @Simon Stelling: I contest that. The question obviously states that he doesn't know the difference between \r\n and \n. I Also explained why \r\n is used (Windows Default) and tried to suggest using Environment.NewLine from here on out.

Comment: @Simon Stelling - that's a harsh assessment. The answer could be improved but I don't think it deserved the downvote (whoever that was).

Comment: @NKCSS - it reads a little as if Environment.Newline IS \r\n - rather than being dependent on OS.

Comment: @James Walford Thanks for the comment; I was hessitant to edit my original text because of the downvote; which I also thought was undeserved. I've rewritten the confusing part.

Comment: @NKCSS: apologies if I came across harsh. I undid my downvote

Answer (score 0):

For reasons mentioned in other answers, only do what EDIT says.
Both are fine, however personally I'd use:

```
regex.split(sometext, "\n");
```

EDIT:

USE Environment.Newline as suggested in other answers.

Comment: Environment.NewLine is the way to go; your example leaves the text with \r char's in some scenario's, which is undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

```
regex.split(sometext, "\r\n");
```

would be the way to do it.

The reason, both appear to give the same result is because,  "\n" breaks the string after the "\r".   So you have a substrings with a trailing "\r", which won't be obvious unless you look at it carefully with a hex editor or something.

That said I'd suggest using Environment.NewLine instead of "\r\n"